# WordPress shows "The site can't be reached" when add a new language in Polylang

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I am building a multilingual WordPress website, and I learned the plugin "Polylang" is a good solution for multilingual.

I activated this plugin after I installed from the official wordpress.org site. But every time when I tried to install a new language, the browser shows me "The site can't be reached" as can be found in the enclosed attachment.

I have tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin and tried to deactivate it then re-activate it. It still goes to the screen shows "The site can't be reached"

**I am using**

*+ WordPress version 4.9.1

+ Polylang 2.2.8*

*My permanent links in WordPress is*

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

*Also, I am using a child theme of Hestia.*

Any suggestion?

Regards

---

The browser shows the following image every time when I add a new language:

[image: The browser shows the following image every time when I add a new language]

Comment: this is not a PHP error but a server error. check is the URL is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The URL is <pre>http://ro***ia.com.au/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mlang&noheader=true</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by logging into the admin of WordPress using Microsoft Edge. I successfully added a new language through the Edge browser.

Still not sure what is wrong with Chrome and connections though.